# SWIFT: How to make an app zoom to your current location on launching?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to build an app that when you open it it zooms to your current location. Below is my code so far.

```
class MapVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    mapView.zoomToUserLocation()
}
}

extension MKMapView {
func zoomToUserLocation() {
    print(userLocation.location?.coordinate)
    guard let coordinate = userLocation.location?.coordinate else { return }
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 10000, 10000)
    setRegion(region, animated: true)
}      
}
```

This code does not solve the problem. I believe this is because the app doesn't have time after receiving location authorisation to obtain the user location. I'm looking to write a function that would wait for the app to have a location and then call the zoomToUserLocation function. I've already tried this with a do-while loop which didn't work. I could set a delay but that would mean the zoom was done at a specific time and instead I want the zoom to be done as soon as possible. I've found solutions to this in objective C but couldn't translate it.

Answer (score 1):

This method might be helpful [`setUserTrackingMode(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1616205-setusertrackingmode), but I think that's not what you are looking for.

The solution that may fit best for you is to implement [`locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager) and [`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) on the `CLLocationManager`'s delegate. Then you call `zoomToUserLocation()` in `didUpdateLocations`.

Another observation, is that you shouldn't animate the map inside `viewDidLoad()` 'cause the view it not on screen yet. This should be done in `viewDidAppead()`.

Comment: Hey, I've called it in both didChangeAuthorization and didUpdateLocations and while both get called write at the start both have a value of nil for the current userlocation.

Answer (score 0):

you need both a span and a region...the span allows you to set how far you want to zoom in...

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
        if let center = location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```